# LeadBolt Ad integrating into AndEngine

Tags: java, android, andengine, leadbolt

I'm trying to integrate the leadbolt "app ad" and "app notification" into my game made with AndEngine.

When I start my game, i get the following errors:

```
07-09 11:42:16.566: D/LBAdController(1262): org.json.JSONException: No value for notificationtype
07-09 11:42:16.566: D/LBAdController(1262):     at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:354)
07-09 11:42:16.566: D/LBAdController(1262):     at org.json.JSONObject.getString(JSONObject.java:510)
07-09 11:42:16.566: D/LBAdController(1262):     at com.Leadbolt.AdController.setNotification(AdController.java:653)
07-09 11:42:16.566: D/LBAdController(1262):     at com.Leadbolt.AdController.initialize(AdController.java:593)
07-09 11:42:16.566: D/LBAdController(1262):     at com.Leadbolt.AdController.loadAd(AdController.java:1103)
07-09 11:42:16.566: D/LBAdController(1262):     at ShogunArts.Tengu.TenguMain.onLoadEngine(TenguMain.java:152)
07-09 11:42:16.566: D/LBAdController(1262):     at org.anddev.andengine.ui.activity.BaseGameActivity.onCreate(BaseGameActivity.java:61)
07-09 11:42:16.566: D/LBAdController(1262):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
07-09 11:42:16.566: D/LBAdController(1262):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
07-09 11:42:16.566: D/LBAdController(1262):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
07-09 11:42:16.566: D/LBAdController(1262):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
07-09 11:42:16.566: D/LBAdController(1262):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
07-09 11:42:16.566: D/LBAdController(1262):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-09 11:42:16.566: D/LBAdController(1262):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-09 11:42:16.566: D/LBAdController(1262):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
07-09 11:42:16.566: D/LBAdController(1262):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-09 11:42:16.566: D/LBAdController(1262):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-09 11:42:16.566: D/LBAdController(1262):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
07-09 11:42:16.566: D/LBAdController(1262):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
07-09 11:42:16.566: D/LBAdController(1262):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

And

```
07-09 11:42:20.715: D/LBAdController(1262): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-09 11:42:20.715: D/LBAdController(1262):     at android.view.ViewConfiguration.get(ViewConfiguration.java:211)
07-09 11:42:20.715: D/LBAdController(1262):     at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:1814)
07-09 11:42:20.715: D/LBAdController(1262):     at com.Leadbolt.AdController.displayAd(AdController.java:1393)
07-09 11:42:20.715: D/LBAdController(1262):     at com.Leadbolt.AdController.access$2(AdController.java:1260)
07-09 11:42:20.715: D/LBAdController(1262):     at com.Leadbolt.AdController$PollRequest.onPostExecute(AdController.java:2456)
07-09 11:42:20.715: D/LBAdController(1262):     at com.Leadbolt.AdController$PollRequest.onPostExecute(AdController.java:1)
07-09 11:42:20.715: D/LBAdController(1262):     at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:417)
07-09 11:42:20.715: D/LBAdController(1262):     at android.os.AsyncTask.access$300(AsyncTask.java:127)
07-09 11:42:20.715: D/LBAdController(1262):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:429)
07-09 11:42:20.715: D/LBAdController(1262):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-09 11:42:20.715: D/LBAdController(1262):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-09 11:42:20.715: D/LBAdController(1262):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
07-09 11:42:20.715: D/LBAdController(1262):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-09 11:42:20.715: D/LBAdController(1262):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
07-09 11:42:20.715: D/LBAdController(1262):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
07-09 11:42:20.715: D/LBAdController(1262):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
07-09 11:42:20.715: D/LBAdController(1262):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-09 11:42:20.715: D/AdController(1262): Exception - null
```

I added the following code into my main class inside the onLoadEngine method adn tested it in the onLoadComplete method, too.

```
public Engine onLoadEngine() { / public void onLoadComplete() {
    myController1 = new AdController(getApplicationContext(), "277481637");
    myController1.setAsynchTask(true);
    myController1.loadNotification();
    myController2 = new AdController(getApplicationContext(), "497251530");
    myController2.loadAd();
    //MORE CODE
    return engine;
}
```

I created a BootReceiver Class (I used the correct packagename):

```
package <PackageName>;

import com.Leadbolt.AdController;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
public class BootReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
        //register the notification on reboot
        AdController mycontroller = new AdController(arg0, "277481637");
        mycontroller.loadNotification();
    }

}
```

and added this to my manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<receiver android:name=".BootReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Maybe someone can help me please.

Comment: Have you tried waiting to load the ad's? Loading them during the engine onLoad may be too soon as the view is still being constructed.

Comment: Also tested to load the ads in the public void onLoadComplete() method and I waited. ( I'm still waiting :) )

Comment: Well it was worth a try, it might be worth following some of threads for other ad implementations on AndEngine. Despite their differences they all essentially need to place a view on top of the rendering view. Might lead you down the right path.

Comment: I looked for various solutions and on another board someone said my code is correct. That's why I don't understand why it doesn't work.

Comment: AndEngine has made a lot of changes over the past year so its quite possible that your code 'was' correct for a previous version.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a review I can see that this line is wrong in your code:

```
myController2 = new AdController(getApplicationContext(), "497251530");
myController2.loadAd();
```

Cant pass in application context for Ads, you need to pass in the Activity.

Also in your Manifest file, include this line:

```
<receiver android:name="com.Leadbolt.AdNotification" />
```

This line needs to be present in your Manifest file before the  tag.

Hope this helps, you can always reach out to us at support@leadbolt.com if you continue to experience issues

Comment: Thanks, the errors don't occur anymore. The ad appears now. But how's the best settings to test if the notification works? And I thought I don't need the `<receiver android:name="com.Leadbolt.AdNotification" />`-Line when I use my own receiver. Or do I need both?

Comment: For my notification I used recurring, start in 10 minutes, repeat 12 hours, show to all users.